# attribute change if the select box not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to check a value of a `select` box which filled according to user choice , this select will be populated once the user select options from `other select boxes` , now in the `document.ready()` the select is empty , i need to check if this select still empty , then disable a button , else , enable it again .

here is what i tried , it senses that the drop box is empty , but not when its populated !

```
if ($('#course-selection').html(null)) {
$('#show-wall-button').attr('disbaled','disabled');
}

else {
$('#show-wall-button').removeAttr('disabled');  
}
```

this already fired on `document.ready` event when the page loads !.

I also tried this , but did not work

```
if ($('#course-selection').val(null)) {
    $('#show-wall-button').attr('disbaled','disabled');
    }

    else {
    $('#show-wall-button').removeAttr('disabled');  
    }
```

Comment: First, using the `val(null)` method means you are attempting to _set_ the value, not _get_ the value. Use `val()` if you simply want to _get_ the value. Secondly, when does the event to check the value of the select happen after the user has populated it?

Comment: `disabled` is spelt `disbaled`, which is wrong

Comment: @swapnilsarwe `sisabled` is spelt `disabled` :)

Comment: @mattytommo thanks for pointing, already corrected, but in the example `disabled` is spelt wrong (`disbaled`) hence it will never removeAttr `disabled` when populated

Comment: @swapnilsarwe hehe yeah I seen, np :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$('#show-wall-button').prop('disabled', $('#course-selection').is(':empty'))
```

Comment: i tried this on my script but it did not work , i removed all what i wrote , do i need to put it some where inside my script ? not alone ?

Answer (score 0):

try like:

```
if ($('#course-selection').val() === '') { 
   $('#show-wall-button').prop('disbaled', true);
}

else {
   $('#show-wall-button').prop('disabled', false);  
}
```

From the API: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#course-selection').val(null))
```

should be

```
if ($('#course-selection').val() == '')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `$('#course-selection option').length` instead of the condition you are currently using?
In any case, I sense there may be a better way to do what you want, without having to check whether there are option tags inside the select box.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the contents of the `<select>` is a bit messy. How about you do something like add an attribute `data-populated="false"` and set it to `true` when you populate it. Then you can just check the status of the attribute on the element in your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

go with the suggestion of @Raminson

But in the example `disabled` is spelt wrong (`disbaled`) hence it will never removeAttr `disabled` when populated, coz the attribute which you have assigned is the wrong spelt `disbaled`

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="course-selection">
   <option value="">null</option>
   <option value="1">option1</option>
</select>
```

if you want to get selected value:

```
if($("#course-selection option:selected").val()=="")
   $('#show-wall-button').attr('disbaled', true);
else
   $('#show-wall-button').removeAttr('disabled');
```

if you want to get selected text:

```
if($("#course-selection option:selected").text()=="null")
   $('#show-wall-button').attr('disbaled', true);
else
   $('#show-wall-button').removeAttr('disabled');
```